# Determine all solutions of the linear equation system $A \vec{x} = \vec{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 18\\ -10 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, vectors, systems-of-equations

Could you give me your feedback ?

---

Determine **all** solutions of the linear equation system $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ for

$$A = \begin {bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
-7 & 14 & -28 & -12 & -23 \\
4 & -8 & 12 & 12 & 8 \\
-3 & 6 & -4 & -1 & -14
\end {bmatrix} , \vec{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 18\\ -10 \end{bmatrix} $$

---

Add 3 first row to fourth row, add -4 first row to third row,add 7 first row to second row. Then divide second row by 9, divide third row by -4, divide fourth row by 8. Then add -1 second row to fourth row, add -1 third row to fourth row [EDIT: and add -4 third row to first row]. Then add 2 second row to first row.

$$A = \begin {bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & -9 \\
0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 8 & 8 & -8
\end {bmatrix}  = \begin {bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end {bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end {bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end {bmatrix} $$

$\vec{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 18 \\ 10\\ -4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ -5/2\\ -1/2 \end{bmatrix} = $[EDIT]$ \begin{bmatrix} 12 \\ 2 \\ -5/2\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 16 \\ 2 \\ -5/2\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

So we get $x_3 = -5/2, x_4 = x_5 + 2, $ [EDIT] $ x_1 = 16 + 2x_2 -5x_4 = 16 - 10 + 2x_2 - 5x_5 = 6 + 2x_2 -5x_5$ with $x_2, x_5$ free

[EDIT: forgot to add -4 third row to first row in step 3. Problem solved now]

Is this correct ? When I plug that into a calculator https://matrix.reshish.com/gaussSolution.php they get the same result except $x_1 = 6 + 2x_2 -5x_5$, is this something to worry about ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Which part of your solution are you unsure about?

Comment: @DanielHast Well maybe I did a calculation mistake somewhere I don't know

Comment: @DanielHast When I plugged that into a calculator https://matrix.reshish.com/gaussSolution.php I get the same result except that they get $x_1 = 6 + 2x_2 -5x_5$ Is this worrying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took these steps

- $(01)~ R_2: R_2 + 7 R_1$
- $(02)~ R_3: R_3 - 4 R_1$
- $(03)~ R_4: R_4 + 3 R_1$
- $(04)~$ Swap $R_2$ with $R_4$
- $(05)~ R_3: R_3 + \dfrac{1}{2} R_2$
- $(06)~$ Swap $R_3$ with $R_4$
- $(07)~ R_4: R_4 -\dfrac{4}{9} R_3$
- $(08)~ R_3: \dfrac{1}{9} R_3$
- $(09)~ R_2: R_2 - 8 R_3$
- $(10)~ R_1: R_1 - 3 R_3$
- $(11)~ R_2: \dfrac{1}{8} R_2$
- $(12)~ R_1: R_1 - 4 R_2$

The final result is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\dfrac{5}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

This means

$$x_4 = 2 + x_5, x_3 = -\dfrac{5}{2}, x_1 = 6 + 2 x_2 -5 x_5$$

You answer has an issue. You should get the same as the book.

You can test it by plugging it back in and seeing that it does not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, forgot to add -4 third row to first row for $\vec{b}$ in step three. When doing that $x_1 = 16 + 2x_2 - 5x_4 = 6 + 2x_2 - 5x_5$ Doing that results in the same as yours Thank you so much for your support